# Is it appropriate to include a List/Summary of Theorems in a paper?

Tags: publications, mathematics, paper-submission

I am 16 years old at the time of writing (so I have no supervisors to seek advice from), and I'm working on a Mathematics paper at the moment, which I plan on submitting to a journal for publication. In the paper I have about 9 lemmas and theorems in total; they are all just formulaic (by formulaic, I mean that they are all just formulae rather than an idea or property about something, eg for argument's sake the quadratic or cubic formula).

Is it a good idea for me to include a list/summary of lemmas and theorems in the paper after my introduction, or should I simply include a couple of the main results in the introduction and not bother with a list of formulae I establish?

It just seems to me that to see all of the results without a summary near the beginning would be quite hard; you'd have to scroll down many pages.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: That is what abstract and introduction are for.

Comment: @dodd In the abstract shouldn't I just give a very brief overview of what I do in the paper, rather than listing the actual formulae?

Comment: In the abstract you say what is done in the paper in general terms. like "we solve the problem X" or "We study X and prove Y" and the introduction should contain a detailed description of the main results and methods and the relationship between your results and the prior results.

Comment: Take a look at some existing papers in your area, and see what they look like.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the paper? And what do you mean about the theorems and lemmas being formulaic?

Comment: @DanRomik I am planning on submitting it to a journal, for publication. About them being 'formulaic', I guess that isn't a proper term, sorry- I mean that they aren't ideas or properties of something, but rather they'reformulae eg for argument's sake something like the quadratic formula. I have now edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: @dodd thank you very much for this clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is most appropriate and would give your paper the best chance of being taken seriously by the research community, is if it conforms to the writing conventions of the field.

The writing conventions of the field do not include having a list of theorems. Therefore, I’d advise you not to include such a list.

Good luck with the paper!

Comment: Thank you for the advice and good wishes! :)

Answer (score 5):

If the lemmas and theorems are unrelated (unlikely) then a list might be fine. But if the purpose of the paper is to prove the main theorem(s) then giving that purpose and naming just those in the introduction is probably more standard and easier for a reader to get a sense of purpose.

So, my guess is that your second suggestion works better. If there is one main theorem then focus, primarily, on that. But if one or two of the others has some independent use then you could expand a bit.

Mathematicians are used to following a train of proof through a fairly long argument, but knowing the goal ahead of time can be helpful.